# how to change the file download location of firefox using java

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I'm using java with selenium to download multiple files from a site using firefox browser. I need to save those files of specific format to a specific folder path and others to another specific path.

Any solution to achieve this ?

Pls help me ...

Thanks,
KRISH.G

Comment: For a selenium user the text of this question is pretty clear - so I would vote against closing it as "not a real question" - but I do not have enough reputation to vote for reopening it.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous that this question is closed. Granted it may need an edit to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can change download dir with `browser.download.dir`. Then you have to change also `browser.download.folderList` to 2 (that means to take value from `browser.download.dir`).

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/foo/bar"); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

You can't change the profile of existing driver. So if you like to change path again you have to create new WebDriver.